# Custom validator to check if passwords match in Angular 6 and Reactive Form

Tags: angular

I have a form with 4 input fields, 2 for emails and 2 for passwords. I would like to check if the emails and passwords match. I'm using a validator in the form group.

```ts
accountInformation: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.accountInformation = this.fb.group({
      emailAddress: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
      emailAddressConfirmed: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
      password: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])],
      passwordConfirmed: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])],
    }, {validator: this.matchValidator});
  }

matchValidator(form: FormGroup) {
    const passwordInput = form['value'];
    if (passwordInput.password === passwordInput.passwordConfirmed) {
      // These ones gives me errors in console
      this.removeError(this.accountInformation.get('password'), 'mismatch');
      // this.removeError(this.accountInformation.controls, 'mismatch');

      // If I do these...
      // form.controls['password'].setErrors(null);
      // form.controls['passwordConfirmed'].setErrors(null);
      // This will remove all errors of all types
    } else {
      form.controls['password'].setErrors({'mismatch': true});
      form.controls['passwordConfirmed'].setErrors({'mismatch': true});
    }
  }

  removeError(control: AbstractControl, error: string) {
    const err = control.errors; // get control errors
    if (err) {
      delete err[error]; // delete your own error
      if (!Object.keys(err).length) { // if no errors left
        control.setErrors(null); // set control errors to null making it VALID
      } else {
        control.setErrors(err); // controls got other errors so set them back
      }
    }
  }
```

I receive this error in console:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of
undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at FormGroup.push../src/app/components/register/register.component.ts.RegisterComponent.matchValidator
[as validator]
```

In those fields I have also `required` and `minlength` and I don't want to lose them if I do `setErrors(null)`. Also I don't know how to check the emails too. Maybe I am complicating the code too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try null check before getting form control's value like this;

```
matchValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    const password: string = control.get('password').value; // get password from our password form control
    const passwordConfirmed: string = control.get('passwordConfirmed').value; // get password from our passwordConfirmed form control
    // compare is the password math
    if (password !== passwordConfirmed) {
        // if they don't match, set an error in our passwordConfirmed form control
        control.get('passwordConfirmed').setErrors({ mismatch: true });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, with your code the error of "passwords do not match" is always visible, don't disappears. Also, other errors like `required` or `minlength` doesn't show up because as I can see in the console, inside of `errors` only `mismatch` is there. Any idea about what's going on?

Comment: Hey @RobertGomez, i updated the code. Can you try this?

Comment: Hi my friend, we are almost there, I edited a little bit the conditions to wait until both fields are valid before the comparisson. Errors are showing but, if both are valid and you edit one field, you see the error, which is correct but the thing is that if you have both fields equal again, one of both fields keep the error visible. Maybe we need to clear the errors in a specific moment? I'm not sure. See your code and my edition here: https://codeshare.io/adxJNB. Screenshot of the behavior: https://ibb.co/bmKtvSQ. Any idea? I tried to do `setErrors(null)` after comparison but didn't work.

Comment: Can you share your HTML with me?

Comment: Hi, I have prepared an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqemsr. You can check the behavior that I have mentioned.

Comment: Actually, there is a logical error here. The passwordConfirmed must be equal to the passowrd, not the password to passwordConfirmed. So it's not right to show you a mismatch mistake under the password. If you delete this line, the problem will be solved in every sense: **control.get('password').setErrors({mismatch: true});**

Comment: You are right. What about if I want to show the error message in both fields? I tried a lot of ways but, only a field keeps the error message, not both. Should I show the error message only in `confirmedPassword`? Will this way be more logical to the user? In addition, how can I check the emails too? doing the same we did inside the `matchValidator` function but referring to `emailAddress` field? I guess this way the function will grow enough if I repeat all the code twice.

Comment: Yes, i think you should show error message only under confirmedPassword. And for confirm emailAddress i updated your code on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5fwd1c I'm not sure this is the best way, but it solves the problem.

Comment: Yeah, at least solves the problem. Thanks a lot my friend.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set errors to null only if there no other mistakes in errors array. You may check length for example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me. I tried to do it inside of `matchValidator` function but, I receive another error. Can you help me with an example or something that I can follow please? Maybe I'm doing it wrong.